# Finding a function with given conditions

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I want to find the equation of a function $f(x)$ such that the following conditions are met:

$(i)\ f(3) = 0, f(0) =1$.

$(ii)\ f(x)$ is an even function.

$(iii)\ f(x)$ has vertical asymptodes at $x=\pm 4$.

$(iv)\ f(x)$ has horizontal asymptode at $ y=2$.

Now since the function is even, I get $x=-3$ as another root and then I can graph the function. But how do I find its equation? Any hints? Thank you.

In general is there some method or software to find the equation of a function given its graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use building blocks having one or more of the wanted properties and put them together conveniently so that the final function $f$ has all wanted properties.

> - We start with (iii) and take as function with asymptote at $x=\pm 4$ the rational function 
>     \begin{align*}
>   x\to\frac{1}{(x-4)(x+4)}=\frac{1}{x^2-16}\tag{1}
>   \end{align*}
>
>   which is already even.

To get a zero at $x=3$ we multiply with $x-3$ and to keep the function even we multiply with $(x-3)(x+3)=x^2-9$.

> - We obtain
>     \begin{align*}
>   x\to\frac{x^2-9}{x^2-16}\tag{2}
>   \end{align*}

Note that $\frac{x^2-9}{x^2-16}$ evaluated at $x=0$ is $\frac{9}{16}$.

> - We multiply the function (2) with $\frac{16}{9}$ and obtain with
>     \begin{align*}
>   x\to\frac{16}{9}\cdot\frac{x^2-9}{x^2-16}\tag{3}
>   \end{align*}
>     an even function which fulfills (i) and (ii).

Finally we extend (3) to get a function with horizontal asymptote at $y=2$. Note that  multiplying the function with $e^{-x^2}$ gives 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{x^2-9}{x^2-16}e^{-x^2}=0
\end{align*}

Since we also have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{x^2-9}{x^2-16}=1
\end{align*}

we          use  the  Ansatz
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\frac{16}{9}\cdot\frac{x^2-9}{x^2-16}\left(ae^{-x^2}+b\right)
\end{align*}
solve
\begin{align*}
f(0)&=a+b=1\\
\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)&=\frac{16}{9}b=2
\end{align*}
and  find $a=-\frac{1}{8}$ and $b=\frac{9}{8}$.

> - We finally obtain a function
>     \begin{align*}
>   &\color{blue}{f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\setminus\{\pm 4\}}\\
>   &\color{blue}{f(x)=\frac{2}{9}\cdot\frac{x^2-9}{x^2-16}\left(-e^{-x^2}+9\right)}
>   \end{align*}
>     which fulfills (i) to (iv).

*Note:* To find an even function is usually not a problem. When we have a function $g$ fulfilling all other properties we can take $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(g(x)+g(-x)\right)$ to get an even function with the wanted properties.

Comment: Thanks this helps.

Comment: @Rick:  You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you want to find **a** rather than **all** functions that satisfy that property. You can approach this with a sort of an ad hoc method.

First lets find some function $f(x)$ that satisfies $(i)$. This should be easy enough, the polynomial $x(x-3)$ does the job. (This i incorrect as I misread the condition to be $f(0) = 0$, this is fixed in the edit below)

Now for $(ii)$, we want $f(x) = f(-x)$. Notice squaring a number makes its sign redundant so we try incorporating that into our function to get $x^2(x^2-9)$. (always check back to see you havent lost $(i)$)

$(iii)$ requires us to divide by $0$ when $x = \pm 4$. So let $$f(x) = \frac{x^2(x^2-9)}{(x-4)(x+4)} = \frac{x^2(x^2-9)}{(x^2-16)}$$

Notice how this still has properties $(i)(ii)$

Finally, we need the horizontal asymptotic condition. Notice right now that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \infty$ since the numerator is of degree $4$ while the denominator is of degree $2$. We can first let $f(x)$ converge when $x$ goes to infinity simply by squaring the denominator. This results in 
$$f(x) = \frac{x^2(x^2-9)}{(x^2-16)^2}$$

This gives us a horizontal asymptote of $y=1$. Multiplying our function by $2$ then fixes this
$$f(x) = 2\frac{x^2(x^2-9)}{(x^2-16)^2}$$
we are done.

EDIT (Sorry for the error)
we remove the $x^2$ and the square on the denominator to get $\frac{2(x^2-9)}{x^2 - 16}$ Notice at $x = 0$ this evaluates to $9/8$. We want to add a term that disappears at $x = \pm 3$ and as $x \rightarrow \infty $ and evaluates to $-1/8$ when $x = 0$. Following similar line of reasoning as above we get $\frac{(x^2 - 9)16^2}{9(8)(x^2 - 16)^2}$  so our function becomes
$$f(x) = \frac{2(x^2-9)}{x^2 - 16} + \frac{(x^2 - 9)16^2}{9(8)(x^2 - 16)^2} = (\frac{x^2-9}{x^2 -16})(2+ \frac{32}{9(x^2 -16)})$$

Comment: It doesn't satisfy $f(0) = 1$. I got everything as you answered but how to fix $f(0) =1?$

Comment: Oh sorry I misread I thought the condition was $f(0) = 0$. This will be fixed in an edit

Comment: Does this new function have a horizontal asymptote at $y=2 ?$

Comment: Yes by the requirement that the added term goes to $0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @ZiadFakhoury: Nice solution (+1). You might want to simplify the last expression by factoring out common terms.

Comment: So there can be more than one functions which satisfy such conditions, are there more of them? How do I know them?

Comment: Thanks for your post @ZiadFakhoury

Comment: This is why I assumed at the beginning that you were only looking for **a** single function. Classifying all the functions that would satisfy your properties would be too hard (atleast for me, there are plenty more experienced and smarter people out there!). However I can tell you there are an infinite amount since adding $(\frac{x^2-9}{(x^-16)^n})(1+ \frac{16}{x^2-16}) $ to $f(x)$ still preserves the properties.